# Lambda that check if pull request hanging more than x time

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, github, aws-lambda

I'm new here and at the development world.
I want to write code in python that connect to my organization and give me back list of all the PR that open more than x time and their owners every start of the day.
How can i connect to github through my pycharm and get things back from github?
There is some service at AWS that can help me get those details?
I searched a lot in the internet and found nothing.

Comment: sadly this is probably too broad.  Github has an api which can do everything you want; you could start there. https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/getting-started-with-the-rest-api

Comment: I Saw this. i want to write my code in python and not using sql queries.
I know it's too broad but i still don't find anything about github PRS through python

Comment: the api I linked to is not writen in sql: it's github's http (REST) api. there are likely python libraries out there to help if you don't want to write the queries by hand

Comment: e.g. https://github.com/PyGithub/PyGithub  Note that this really is too broad, but if I were setting out to do this, I'd start by checking out the existing libraries like that one (google 'github python bindings' or the like to see what else is out there.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.